# request not made for cross-domain within iframe

Tags: node.js, cross-domain

I have developed an app for backend in nodejs that is located at some domain (say B). My frontend in angularjs at another domain (say A). I have added an iframe at domain 'A' in which domain 'B' is embedded within iframe. While i am running the site say http://A.com/admin, for chrome & firefox no problem occurs. But on safari & ie the site is running but i am not been able to login i.e any http request not served. I am suspecting it's a case of CROSS-DOMAIN. I have used p3p module for nodejs and used it as a middleware. but nothing happen.

I am totally confused. is there any way to do it or what is the solution to get out of this problem?

Thanks in advance. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried editing CORS on server B?

Comment: Hi karan can you explain a bit?

Comment: No matter if it's an iframe or not, when you request for something of domain A from domain B, then it will work only if you have CORS enabled on server B.

Comment: Checkout http://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html

Comment: i think you did not understand my problem. I think CORS is only considerable  for any type ajax request for different domain. My app is CORS enabled and that's why any request served for chrome & firefox. But that is not the my case. Here i am not been able to login my backend app directly when it is within iframe.

Comment: Then it might be a CORS related issue, maybe it's a UI issue? Safari behaves weirdly with many websites

Comment: nope while i am running the server without the iframe its running fine. But within iframe problem occurs. may be its the case of cookie also.

Comment: yea, maybe - why are you using the iframe btw?